# custom gridview controls that supports paging, sorting, searching

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am  looking   for custom  gridview  controls that  supports paging, sorting, searching.   is  there   any  controls[ that has   all builtin  functionality] so that i can just drag and drop this  control.    in the page  i ll  just  send that datatable as  paramter to  the  custom gridview control. all the functionlity  will  be     done  at  custom gridview  control.
 if there  is  any control that  does  this  job.

Answer (score 3):

Telerik builds a grid ([RadGrid for ASP.NET AJAX](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/performance/linq/defaultcs.aspx)) that has those features and more out of the box. Very easy to use, drag-and-drop (designer) friendly.